# Disable some Win+X hotkeys for Explorer from RegEdit under Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-registry, autohotkey, hotkeys

How to disable *some* of `Win+X` keys that are registered to Explorer so that they could be used by other software (e.g. disabling `Win+I` and `Win+P` and then mapping these keys *from within* Search Everything to some of Everything functions).

It is possible to disable *all* `Win+X` through `gpedit.msc`. And it is also easy to simply remap *some* `Win+X` keys to empty via AutoHotKey. And *sending* those keys to the target program (e.g. Everything) via AutoHotKey could solve the issue.

I [found](http://www.geoffchappell.com/notes/windows/shell/explorer/globalhotkeys.htm) that this could be a potential answer. However, I created `DisabledHotkeys` of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced` using `regedit` as suggested there, and set its value to `HIKU`. After restarting Windows 8.1, those keys are still caught by Explorer. I am aware that `Win+L` could be another story.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it may be easier just to map the keys of interest with AutoHotkey to either do nothing or to send various shortcut keys or keystrokes to other programs you'd like to use the key combo for.

For example:

```
#p::        ; Globally ignore Win+P
IfWinActive, Notepad
    Send ^p      ; remap to Ctrl+P for Notepad
return
```

You would be able to create multiple shortcuts for different programs using the IfWinActive statements.

Alternate syntax...

```
#IfWinActive, Notepad    ; doesn't globally ignore #p if it is executed elsewhere
#p::Send ^p
```